# Modifier.clip being ignored

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-image

I have a basic `Image` with a `painterResource` from my drawale folder.

I'm trying to make it a rounded image but the clip modifier isn't doing anything.

This is one way I've tried.

```
@Composable
fun roundImage(){
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.profilepicexample),
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize(0.2f)
            .clip(CircleShape),
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
    )
}
```

I've also tried putting the image in a box/card and clipping that but it still does nothing!

What am I missing here?

Update:
Current Code

```
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
@Composable
fun AdminPeopleLocationsScreen(modifier: Modifier, navController: NavController){
    val appRepo = AppRepository()
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ){
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.bgtest),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(0.4f)
                .aspectRatio(1f)
                .clip(CircleShape),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
    }
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

update 2: Still stuck on this, playing around I found that it shows the clipping in a @Preview but removes it on the device.

Comment: Your code draws a perfect circle to me. Make sure it's the exact view you're viewing on the screen. Try commenting it out to see if it disappears. If that's not the case, please create a clear project, try to reproduce the problem there and add a GitHub link to such sample to your answer

Comment: I created a new project using the same dependencies and fragments and wasn't able to reproduce the problem. I still can't get the clip to apply, all other modifiers such as size are working and changing the image. Super frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and this worked to me:

```
@Composable
fun MyImageAdvance() {
    val image = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
            .padding(16.dp)
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = image,
            contentDescription = "my description for disabled people",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier
                .clip(CircleShape)
        )
    }
}
```